# Pass multiple values in link

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have three values that I want to pass via a link, but don't want them visible in the URL.

Comment: that's nonsense. link and url are the same. can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out using this example with javascript.
http://www.skytopia.com/project/articles/compsci/form.html#form2php

Answer (score 6):

> I have three values that I want to
>   pass via a link, but don't want them
>   visible in the URL.

Your statement is contradictory to itself. You want to show in link but at the same time you don't want to show it in the url.

Alternatively, you can use ***hidden fields*** to pass your data or even use ***session***.

Answer (score 2):

There are two main methods to do it:

Firstly, if you're using forms:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="POST">
    ... stuff ...
</form>
```

This will store the form contents into PHP's $_POST array, depending on the element name. So, if you have an element with `name="foo"`, it'll go into $_POST['foo']. You can use hidden form fields (`type="hidden"`) so that they don't display.

Another way is via sessions (think of them as server-side cookies), stored inside of $_SESSION:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['foo'] = value;
```

If you want to remove *all* the session variables, use `session_destroy()`.

See here for more info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php

Answer (score 0):

you can pass these variables in a hidden form with POST. Alternatively, you could encode the values somehow so they are not human readable.

Comment: Not quite sure how to mask the form as a link.

Comment: I've seen it done with javascript, but only one value at a time. Ex. <a href="#" onclick="document.myform.formVar.value='first'; document.myform.submit(); return false">Click 1st</a><br>

Comment: This can be done, for example, with JavaScript: on link click you submit form with hidden values.

Answer (score 0):

Then you've got a problem, as a link is basically a URL that the browser will follow when clicked. You could simply include the values in the link URL and have the page that URL identifies redirect to another URL. That way, at least the values won't show up in the address bar. Whether or not this will achieve your [overall goal](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal), I couldn't say.